# My OPENSSL embedded program can connect to some servers, however cannot connect to some servers

Tags: openssl

My problem;

I tried some the hostname addresses to connect to the server via embedded system.

Unfortunately, I took a the connect error.

Instance, I can connect to "www.google.com" while cannot connect to "www.wikipedia.org."

The `res = SSL_connect(ssl)` function returne -1 of value.

I retrieve "unknown error code" when I call  function to `result = ERR_error_string(err, buf);`.

```
int rl_ssl_fetch_webpage(void)
{   
long res = 1;
int ret = 1;
unsigned long ssl_err = 0;
int sockfd = 0;
SSL *ssl = NULL;
SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;


init_openssl();

do{ 
    const SSL_METHOD *method = SSLv23_client_method();

    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();        
    if(method == NULL){
        error_msg(ssl_err, "SSLv23_client_method");
        break; 
    }

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();
    if(ctx == NULL){
       error_msg(ssl_err, "SSL_CTX_new");
       break;
    }

    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);         

    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();
    if(ssl == NULL){
        error_msg(ssl_err, "SSL_new");
        break;
    }



    sockfd = conn_socket();

    res = SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();
    if(res != 1){
        error_msg(ssl_err, "SSL_set_fd");
        break;
    }

    res = SSL_connect(ssl);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();
    if(res != 1){
        ssl_err = ERR_get_error();
        error_msg(res, "SSL_connect");
        break;
    }..........
```

---

```
static int conn_socket(void)
{
int res, sockfd;
struct addrinfo hints = {}, *srvaddrs; 

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));   
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

if((res = getaddrinfo(HOST_NAME, HOST_PORT, &hints, &srvaddrs)) != 0){
    perror("ERROR: getaddrinfo()\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if((sockfd = socket(srvaddrs->ai_family, srvaddrs->ai_socktype, srvaddrs->ai_protocol)) < 0){
    perror("ERROR: socket()\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 2; //seconds 
timeout.tv_usec = 0; //microseconds
socklen_t opt_len = sizeof(timeout);

setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (void *) &timeout, opt_len);

if(connect(sockfd, srvaddrs->ai_addr, srvaddrs->ai_addrlen) != 0){
    close(sockfd);      
    perror("ERROR: connect()\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

freeaddrinfo(srvaddrs); 

return sockfd;  
}
```

---

header file

```
#ifndef __RL_OPENSSL_H__
#define __RL_OPENSSL_H__

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> 


#define HOST_NAME   "www.wikipedia.org" //non-working
//#define HOST_NAME "www.google.com"    //working 

#define HOST_PORT "443"
#define HOST_RESOURCE "/ "

#endif
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Some servers may not accept to communicate using `SSL v2/v3`, because they are not considered secure anymore. You should therefore not use `SSLv23_client_method()`, but `TLSv1_1_method()` or `TLSv1_2_method()` instead.

You can try connecting with `openssl s_client` to see if the server is accepting connections, for example:

```
openssl s_client -connect  www.google.com:443  -tls1
```

You will get a lot of interesting information/error messages:

```
openssl s_client -connect  www.google.com:443  -tls1
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = www.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=www.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=GTS CA 1O1
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=GTS CA 1O1
   i:/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=www.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=GTS CA 1O1
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: MD5-SHA1
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3223 bytes and written 205 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.0, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 26FD4773D0080E5A82A50879045993898C39ED81ED5F5952F2C50A5994143EB1
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 5358DCE2846B87848015E97A904405CDB0B24D30002A890E51C3007A6AB63B34E7903035F5E0054B7A91E8B3FC087D7B
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 01 83 ab 00 79 09 65 62-06 e5 5b 4d 14 72 6f 99   ....y.eb..[M.ro.
    0010 - f8 76 35 6d f7 11 81 a9-b7 f6 9b 0a f6 5a ec 9a   .v5m.........Z..
    0020 - 3b cc 96 f5 20 17 ec 67-2d 6f e7 8b 54 c2 40 2a   ;... ..g-o..T.@*
    0030 - cc 22 ba 93 04 55 e6 6d-79 59 22 d7 f2 78 b8 0a   ."...U.myY"..x..
    0040 - 2b a5 e1 e2 b3 00 0d 95-ef e1 54 a4 eb e3 e3 5b   +.........T....[
    0050 - 42 b8 e4 63 e9 4e f7 b0-24 a0 bb 3d 47 d6 97 17   B..c.N..$..=G...
    0060 - c2 8d 18 1b e8 ea ff c4-4d 67 b3 16 d4 62 5d aa   ........Mg...b].
    0070 - 51 74 dc 06 d1 93 32 b5-2c 3c dc 52 ef 70 ca d1   Qt....2.,<.R.p..
    0080 - fd 40 3f 63 e1 d7 01 d7-31 b1 68 31 cd eb 81 1c   .@?c....1.h1....
    0090 - cb ac c9 54 77 64 66 40-17 9f d8 07 79 f1 e1 c9   ...Twdf@....y...
    00a0 - ba 1d ef fb 35 c0 bc b8-54 fc 5f df 0f a7 a9 5d   ....5...T._....]
    00b0 - 3a cb f0 18 0c 9b 06 15-27 f2 d2 1d 00 b0 88 0b   :.......'.......
    00c0 - c3 d0 89 3c 06 06 19 bf-a9 a1 f9 9b 96 64 64 d0   ...<.........dd.
    00d0 - 80 09 d5 4c 15 65 4d ad-99 24 db 61 17 ff d6 c7   ...L.eM..$.a....
    00e0 - c1 14                                             ..

    Start Time: 1586289576
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
openssl s_clientread:errno=0
```

This should help you investigating further why you can connect to some servers, and not to others.

Comment: I thank for your tips give me. 
However, I work on a the embedded system which not support TLSv1_1_method() and TLSv1_2_method(), It only available SSLv23_client_method() and SSLv3_client_method().

Comment: @muhammed_h: Did you validate with `openssl s_client` the assumption that using `SSLv2`/`SSLv3` was the reason why you could not connect to certain servers ? What are exactly the processor/operating system you are using ? this should not be difficult than to recompile the latest version of openssl for your embedded system - I could assist you in that. But you need to validate first that `SSLv2`/`SSLv3` is causing the issue.

Comment: I'm using the real-time operation system (eCos) and chip (gx6605s). In this the system openssl functions define to Cyassl functions. Actually I am using the cyassl library.

Comment: I have  been been updating an old openssl library in an eCos system myself, I therefore feel your pain :-). In this case, you should probably migrate to [wolfSSL](https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl), the successor library to cyassl, which does support up to TLSv1.3. This should not require  a lot of work, and I would definitively not put a device on any network those days which is only SSLv2/SSLv3 capable. Either you are secure or you are not.

Comment: I thank for you help again. I have been felt good not be lonely reason same pain.-:)  I'll pay attention to your valuable suggestions.

Comment: In the case you could get a proof that your problem is caused by the use of SSLv2/SSLv3 instead of TLSv1.2/TLSv1.3, say by testing with `openssl s_client`),  please feel free to accept the answer above, it may be helpful to others, besides being rewarding to me.

Comment: I tried change  cyassl library, but it uses other libraries, therefore I cannot change.  So my hand haven't any a proof related to use with SSLv2/SSLv3  instead of TLSv1.2/TLSv1.3. I used "openssl s_client" on terminal and I can see servers use which the protocol.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal program I could compile, a  public server this program can connect to, and a public server it cannot ?

Comment: Alright I can share. How do you want via on here or email?

Comment: Here is fine:  just add the code for `conn_socket()` to the code above, the version of `cyassl`you are using, and and examples of a working/non-working public server.

Comment: I'm using the version "2.4.6" of libcyassl. I added  extra codes below of the question.